# Incompatibility due to GUID

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i have flatfile which has a field accountid(ex:123123123) .

I need to import my accountid which is in flatfile to database in which it is also named accountid(uniqueidentifier,null)(it's a GUID unique identifier)

Tried changing the metadata of flat to unique identifier but am getting error.

> [Flat File Source [2]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data
>   conversion for column "Account Id" returned status value 2 and status
>   text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of
>   data.". [Flat File Source [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Flat File
>   Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Account Id]" failed
>   because error code 0xC0209084 occurred, and the error row disposition
>   on "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Account
>   Id]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified
>   object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: The issue seems to be with a column called "Contact Id", not "accountid", you should edit your question to include an example of the file and database for more specific help.

Comment: Are the types used in your file the same types as used in your database?

Comment: yes remaining are same.... am just getting error with this field only

Comment: Then you need to post the explicit layout of your file and database so that we can actually see what may be going on

Comment: due to security reasons I cannot do that but the info provided should be good regarding error and column in both flat file and DB

Comment: I'm not sure how providing the layout is a security risk, but with the presented information I am unable to assist you further

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're trying to convert an integer into a GUID?

Comment: @Tab Alleman ....it is string-->GUID

Comment: AccoundId field values has to be of GUID type. Is that happening? I would suggest to keep the source as string as is without converting and at the destination you can have error redirection configured to check which ones have failed.

Answer (score 1):

Create field for storing source accountid as integer. Add derived column with generated GUID id's (howto [Create a GUID column in SSIS](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/02/create-guid-column-in-ssis.html)) to your source data and use it as primary key in target.

If you trying import GUID values with the same error message:

> [Flat File Source [2]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "AccountId" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."...

or (the same in Russian):

> [Flat File Source [177]] Error: Ошибка преобразования данных. При преобразовании данных для столбца "accountid" возращено значение состояния 2 и текст состояния "Невозможно преобразовать значение из-за возможной потери данных.".
>
> [Flat File Source [177]] Error: Код ошибки служб SSIS: DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. Сбой Flat File Source.Выводы[Выход источника "Неструктурированный файл"].Столбцы[accountid] из-за возникновения ошибки с кодом 0xC0209084, и стратегия обработки ошибок строк в "Flat File Source.Выводы[Выход источника "Неструктурированный файл"].Столбцы[accountid]" определяет сбой по ошибке. Ошибка возникла в указанном объекте указанного компонента. Возможно, до этого были опубликованы сообщения об ошибках, в которых содержатся более подробные сведения о причине сбоя.

**Dublecheck that GUID values have curly braces.** This CSV throws errors:

```
ReqType;accountid;contactid;
0;6E0DAA5D-CB68-4348-A7B2-AD2367190F83;FFA9D382-D534-4731-82A0-D9F36D8221B0;
```

This will be processed:

```
ReqType;accountid;contactid;
0;{6E0DAA5D-CB68-4348-A7B2-AD2367190F83};{FFA9D382-D534-4731-82A0-D9F36D8221B0};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by importing your flat file to a Staging table that has a varchar datatype for `AccountId`.

Then call a stored procedure that copies the data from the staging table to your final destination and uses `TRYPARSE()` to convert the `AccountId` column to a GUID.  Then you will be able to handle the rows that don't have a valid GUID in the `AccountId` column without losing the rows that do.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem importing GUIDs from an Excel file into a table having uniqueidentifier column. Turned out the SQL import wizard throws the dreaded potential data loss error if the GUIDs are not wrapped in {}.

```
Ex:  66498FED-E31F-4A6E-930B-C21E44F19CE9  BAD
    {66498FED-E31F-4A6E-930B-C21E44F19CE9} GOOD
```